# Linear program, find vectors that minimize equally weighted sum of $l_1$ norms on a constrained set

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

I have the following constrained minimization problem, where $x,y$ are vectors in $R_+^n$
and $C$ is a matrix of exogenous parameters, $c_{ij} \in R_+$
$$ min_{x \geq 0,y \geq 0} \sum_{i = 1}^n x_i + \sum_{i = 1}^n y_i $$

subject to

$$ \begin{cases}
\begin{align*}
  x_1 + y_1 \geq c_{11} \\
  x_1 + y_2 \geq c_{12} \\
  ... \\
  x_1 + y_n \geq c_{1n}
\end{align*}
\end{cases}
$$
$$ \begin{cases}
\begin{align*}
  x_2 + y_1 \geq c_{21} \\
  x_2 + y_2 \geq c_{22} \\
  ... \\
  x_2 + y_n \geq c_{2n}
\end{align*}
\end{cases}
$$

$$ \begin{align*}
...
   \end {align*}
$$

$$ \begin{cases}
\begin{align*}
  x_n + y_1 \geq c_{n1} \\
  x_n + y_2 \geq c_{n2} \\
  ... \\
  x_n + y_n \geq c_{nn}
\end{align*}
\end{cases}
$$

I am looking for anything that is known about this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your linear programming (LP) problem is to minimize $\sum_i (x_i+y_i)$ subject to
\begin{align}
x_i + y_j &\ge c_{ij} &&\text{for all $i$ and $j$} \\
x_i &\ge 0 &&\text{for all $i$} \\
y_i &\ge 0 &&\text{for all $i$}
\end{align}

The dual LP problem is to maximize $\sum_i \sum_j c_{ij} z_{ij}$ subject to
\begin{align}
\sum_j z_{ij} &\le 1 &&\text{for all $i$} \\
\sum_i z_{ij} &\le 1 &&\text{for all $j$} \\
z_{ij} &\ge 0 &&\text{for all $i$ and $j$}
\end{align}

This dual problem is the [linear assignment problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem) in the complete bipartite graph $K_{n,n}$.